# Creating a new variable containing several levels based on two columns of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python. I am trying to create a new variable based on two columns in the dataset.

```
def cal_freqw(var1, var2):
    if var1 == 1:
        return 0
    elif (var1 == 2 and var2 < 998):
        return 7*var2
    elif var == 3:
        return var2/31;
    elif var1 == 98:
        return 9998
    elif var2 == 998:
        return 9998

df["FREQW"]=cal_freqw(df["UNIT"], df["NUM"])
```

I get this error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

df["UNIT"] and df["NUM"] are integers.(Correction: series of integers)

Because I have several variables like "UNIT" and "NUM" to be computed, a function would help. Could someone help me to fix my calling command?  Thank you!

After editing my code suggested by Zichzheng and others, I still receive this following error message:

```
      2
      3 def cal_freqw(var1, var2):
----> 4     if var1 == 1:
      5         return 0
      6     elif (var1 == 2 & var2 < 998):
 

   1477               1     2
   1478         0  10.0  20.0
-> 1479         >>> df.equals(different_data_type)
   1480         False
   1481         """

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `df["UNIT"] and df["NUM"] are integers` no they are `series of integers` so there is no meaning of `var1 == 1` either `all` series element `==1` or atleast one `any` is `==1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

The **or** and **and** statements need truth-values. And in pandas, they are **ambiguous**. So You need to use **|(OR)** and **&(AND)** to replace them.

So, your code will be:

```
def cal_freqw(var1, var2):
    if var1 == 1:
        return 0
    elif (var1 = 2) & (var2 < 998):
        return 7*var2
    elif var == 3:
        return var2/31;
    elif var1 == 98:
        return 9998
    elif var2 == 998:
        return 9998

df["FREQW"]=cal_freqw(df["UNIT"], df["NUM"])
```

See [this document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) if you want to know more about it.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the replies.  Now I understand that I need to use **&**.  I followed Zichzheng's code, but somehow it shows me the same error message as before.  I will update the error message in my question.

Comment: I think the condition also needs to be inside a (). I just updated my answer. Try: (var1 == 2) & (var2 < 998)

Comment: Thank you very much, Zichzheng.  I just tried including the parentheses.  It gives me the same error messages.

Comment: Can you do a print(df["UNIT"]) and print(df["NUM"])? I would like to know the exact value.

Comment: I am only showing the first 5 observations. Otherwise, it'd be too much. Thank you for helping me to troubleshoot! (Index removed) (UNIT: 98 3 4 3 3)(NUM: 998 3 2 5 20)

Comment: Restricting the function with one variable only still gives the same error message. Changing the series of integers to series of floats also doesn't help.

Comment: Try use " = " instead of '=='

Comment: (if comparing using " = ", " != ") in parenthesis

Comment: And if your df have null values, use 0 to replace them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Zichzheng.  I tried "=", but didn't work, and there's no missing values.  Not sure what's the problem...